# Input Placeholder without padding

Tags: css, sass

Generated by SASS, I'm attempting to write an input that has a center placeholder but a left aligned (with some padding) input text.  I'm still somewhat new to CSS, so please overlook any ignorance.

Setting the padding-left in the input css, I generate 2 problems:

1. When I `text-align:center` the placeholder text, I still have that padding pushing the alignment to the right a bit.
2. When I set a 50% width on the input, it doesn't take the padding into account, thus I get a few pixels + 50% of the parent container.

The following is my SASS code:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
}
input[type=text],input[type=password],input[type=tel],input[type=email] {
 height:$formiconheight;
 width:$formItemMaxWidth;
 margin:5px;
 border-radius:5px;
 padding-left:$formiconwidth + $formInputPadding;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the issue with `padding-left`, you are only adding padding to the left, so it stands to reason that the text won’t be centred. Either don't add any padding or add an equal amount to `padding-left` and `padding-right`.

The width in CSS if for the content box only. Not the content, padding, and border. If you want to include the padding, you should include `box-sizing: border-box` (and `-moz-box-sizing: border-box` for Firefox). This tells the browser to make the width include the padding.

Also, you only include the prefix for WebKit for the placeholder. Firefox and IE also allow you to style the placeholder, so you should include another rule set for both:

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder { }
```

and:

```
input::-moz-placeholder { }
```

If you want to support Firefox < 19, you should also include:

```
input:-moz-placeholder { }
```